# Output of SoftLayer_Account::getNextInvoiceTopLevelBillingItems after Billign Date

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am getting below output when i run SoftLayer_Account::getNextInvoiceTopLevelBillingItems. 20th of every month is my nextBilling date, wanted to know what will be values for hoursUsed,currentHourlyCharge,recurringFee etc for an active device in next Billing cycle.Will it continue with previous value say on 20th hoursUsed =56, if i run same API on 21st will hoursUsed=56+ or will it start from 0;

[
  {
    "allowCancellationFlag": 1,
    "cancellationDate": "2017-02-27T08:49:26-06:00",
    "categoryCode": "guest_core",
    "createDate": "2017-02-27T06:58:38-06:00",
    "currentHourlyCharge": ".048",
    "cycleStartDate": "2017-02-27T07:01:23-06:00",
    "description": "1 x 2.0 GHz Core",
    "domainName": "dom.com",
    "hostName": "febtest",
    "hourlyRecurringFee": ".024",
    "hoursUsed": "2",
    "id": 153540813,
    "laborFee": "0",
    "laborFeeTaxRate": "0",
    "lastBillDate": "2017-02-27T07:01:23-06:00",
    "modifyDate": "2017-02-27T08:51:11-06:00",
    "nextBillDate": "2017-03-20T00:00:00-05:00",
    "oneTimeFee": "0",
    "oneTimeFeeTaxRate": "0",
    "orderItemId": 181368197,
    "parentId": null,
    "recurringFee": ".048",
    "recurringFeeTaxRate": "0",
    "recurringMonths": 1,
    "serviceProviderId": 1,
    "setupFee": "0",
    "setupFeeTaxRate": "0",
    "category": {
      "categoryCode": "guest_core",
      "id": 80,
      "name": "Computing Instance",
      "quantityLimit": 20
    },
    "location": {
      "id": 265592,
      "longName": "Amsterdam 1",
      "name": "ams01",
      "statusId": 2
    },
    "resourceTableId": 28824891
  }
]

Answer (score 0):

The value hoursused are figured out for each new billing cicle it means that the value will start from 0 when a new billing cicle start.

Other values such as hourlyRecurringFee, recurringFee will be the same each new billing cicle, the setupFee will only be in the invoice once (this is when you created the machine) the next invoices you should be charged for that, abd the taxes that depends on the state you are and they could change each billing cicle.

Regards

Comment: Is there any Softlayer API where we can know particular device is billed based on Hourly or monthly.

Comment: what I know is by seeing the billing item, the devices which are charged by hour have a value in the HourlyRecurringFee property and the value in recurringFee is always 0, in another hand the devices which are charged mountly have a value in recurringFee property and 0 for HourlyRecurringFee.

Comment: also these methods could help you http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account/getHourlyBareMetalInstances http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account/getHourlyServiceBillingItems http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account/getHourlyVirtualGuests